# Can I have 2 babelrc files in one project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, preact

I'm trying to add react to a very large solution, but one component on the site uses preact. My current  .bablerc is

```
{
  "presets": ["env"],
  "ignore": [
      "**/what-input.js",
      "**/HostedPCIAdapter.js",
      "InstantPreview/**/*.js",
      "Wishlist/**/*.js"
    ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-react-jsx"
  ]
}
```

Original .baberc looked like this:

```
{
"sourceMaps": true,
"presets": [],
"plugins": [
[
    "transform-react-jsx",
{
    "pragma": "preact.h"
} 
],
"transform-object-assign",
[
    "transform-es2015-classes",
    {
        "loose": true 
    }
],
"transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
"transform-es2015-block-scoping",
"transform-es2015-template-literals"
]

}
```

So can I add pragma back for just the wishlist feature? Any help would be appreciated. I'm using gulp as a taskrunner and webpack to build my assets.

Comment: Have you tried it? Shouldn't be a problem, depending on how things are being built, but then there are workarounds of course

Comment: But wouldn’t i need them both at root directory? I suppose i could make a bable rc generation script, but the react is being build with gulp-webpack and the preact is being built through gulp-babel. I would love to update the preact code to react but it’s too much work with my deadline.

Comment: sure put them both on the root just don't name them exactly `.babelrc`. you don't need a fancy script, just `cp .preact.babelrc .babelrc` before building or something. again this kind of depends on what your build pipeline is expecting but that seems easy enough to me

Comment: gulp runs in order... just rename the file directly in your gulpfile, then rename the other one, then delete the `.babelrc` at the end to cleanup

Comment: if you post your gulpfile it might be easier to show you my simple solution

Comment: I figured it out. I should have just dug deeper into the docks. Turns out you can have multiple .babelrc files and they are searched recursively. so every sub directory can have it's own specifications which is really cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel files can be nested in sub-directories with unique settings which is pretty cool stuff.

So if you have a folder structure like this:

```
app
    reactCode
        .babelrc
        index.js
    preactCode
        .babelrc
        index.js
```

You can add a separate .babelrc file for branch. 
I don't think it's ideal but if you're working with a large monolithic solution that has lots of different frameworks and requirements it certainly can fix a lot of bugs and QA work.